# How do I change the battleground ranges for AzerothCore

Tags: azerothcore

I am running a solo server on my machine. I am not really planning on anyone else playing with me. I wanted to mess around with the battle ground ranges, as I want to farm up a BIS level 60 (on my TBC server) and do battlegrounds while level 60, without getting stat checked by level 69 bots (I have not tried it, maybe this won't happen anyway). The goal I am trying to achieve is either creating a battle ground bracket for level 60's or include level 60 in the 50's battleground bracket.
The ideal brackets would be as follows:
10-19
20-29
30-39
40-49
50-60
61-69
70

I attempted to look around in the database to figure out where the brackets are being defined, but was unable to find them. The `battleground_template` table, which I assumed would have the definitions, did not have an obvious place to make the bracket changes. I thought maybe the brackets just worked as a +X0 from the start, so I attempted to shift the start of WSG to 11 and then attempted to join as a level 60 and was still in game with a bunch of level 60+'s. I looked for any other references to battleground and did not find anything that seemed promising.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the `PvpDifficulty.dbc` in your `dbc` folder. The access requirements for this are hardcoded; you need to modify this and create a new patch that you put in your data folder.

You can create a folder called `Patch-X.mpq`, if you don’t know how to create a patch.

Example:

```
Data/patch-x.mpq/DBFilesClient/PvpDifficulty.dbc
```